# Prove that if $\sum u_n$ is convergent, then $\sum\sqrt[n]n\,u_n$ is also convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series

If $\sum u_n$ is a convergent series then can it be concluded that 
  $\sum\sqrt[n]n\,u_n$ is also convergent

I think that by abels theorem since  $\sqrt[n]n$ is monotone bounded hence the above theorem holds true

Please help from there

Comment: Yes it is a consequence of Abel's theorem, but not applied to $n^{1/n}$ since it is not monotone. You need to skip a finite number of terms from the beginning since what it really is is eventually decreasing and bounded by $1$ from below.

Comment: Please also show the index: $n\ge?$

Comment: It is more often called an "Abel Test," not [Abel's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem), which is different.

Answer (score 2):

- If $u_n \geq 0$ for all sufficiently large $n$, **yes**. And this is easy.

  *Proof:* without loss of generality, assume $u_n > 0$ for all $n$.
  $
  \lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{n} = 1
  $, so $\sqrt[n]{n}u_n \sim_{n\to\infty}u_n$ and you can conclude by the [limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test).
- If $(u_n)_n$ is allowed arbitrary signs, **yes**. But this is less obvious *(though not horrendous either)*, and as you suggested follows from Abel/Dirichlet's test.
  *(What follows is not the shortest proof, I reckon, but I find it instructive.)* 
  Note that since $$\sqrt[n]{n} = e^{\frac{\ln n}{n}} = 1+ \frac{\ln n}{n}+O\left(\frac{\ln^2 n}{n^2}\right)\tag{1}$$
  when $n\to \infty$, and $\lim_{n\to\infty}{u_n} = 0$ we have
  $$
  \sqrt[n]{n}u_n = u_n + \frac{\ln n}{n}u_n + \varepsilon_n \tag{2}.
  $$
  with $\varepsilon_n = o\left(\frac{\ln^2 n}{n^2}\right)$.
  By assumption, $\sum_n u_n$ is a convergent series. By comparison with a $p$-series, the series $\sum_n \varepsilon_n$ is absolutely convergent. So overall, we have that
  $$
  \sum_n \sqrt[n]{n}u_n
  $$
  converges if, and only if,
  $$
  \sum_n \frac{\ln n}{n}u_n
  $$
  does. So it suffices to prove the latter: this is where [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test) comes in handy: we apply it with $a_n = \frac{\ln}{n}$, $b_n=u_n$, so that (i) $(a_n)_n$ is non-increasing with limit $0$; (ii) the partial sums of $\sum_n b_n$ are uniformly bounded (since $\sum_n u_n$ is convergent. $\square$

Answer (score -1):

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(n+1)^{\frac{1}{n+1}} u_{n+1}}{(n)^{\frac{1}{n}} u_{n}}$$
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\le\frac{(n+1)^{\frac{1}{n}} u_{n+1}}{(n)^{\frac{1}{n}} u_{n}} $$ 
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\le\frac{(\frac{n+1}{n})^{\frac{1}{n}} u_{n+1}}{ u_{n}} $$ 
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\le\frac{(1+\frac{1}{n})^{\frac{1}{n}} u_{n+1}}{ u_{n}} $$

$u_n$ is convergent also $(1+1/n)^{1/n}$

Comment: The signs of $u_n$ are not known.

Comment: This is not how we do ratio test formally. You missed the absolute value and limit. Also, what if $\lim_{n\to\infty}|u_{n+1}/u_n|=1$? Then your test shows nothing at all!

Comment: In addition, if you do ratio test correctly, you still get $\lim_{n\to\infty}|a_{n+1}/a_n|\le 1$ which is not sufficient to prove convergence.

Comment: @upvoter Care to explain your vote?